# Codeigniter PHP display a value of array

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter.

when need to display 5th element value of an array in java normally we use,

```
System.out.print(array[4]);
```

in controller of codeigniter I use,

```
$data['test'] = $this->Model_test->getValues();
```

to assign value into the array. and then I use,

```
$this->load->view('test_view', $data);
```

to load view.

inside view I use,

```
foreach ($questions as $object) {
    echo $object->question;
}
```

to display all values. If I need to display only the value of 5th element, what should I do?

Comment: Is it an array or an array of object if its an array you can simply use `$questions[5]` for array of object `$questions->5`

Comment: If $object is an array then you could simply use $object[4] which will print the fifth index position value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
foreach ($questions as $object) {
    echo $object->question;
}
```

Above will echo each row's question. to get only 5th row, check this.

```
echo $questions[5]->question;
```

Comment: ...wait, if `$object` is an object (stated when he showed us `$object->question`), how do you plan on using array subscript to access a property?

Comment: [Check This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33686670/codeigniter-php-display-a-value-of-array#comment55145743_33686670)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
print_r($questions[4]); # This will print fifth element of an array
```